# Using both When and Protected methods on the same member setup with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Is there a way to use both `Mock.Protected` and `Mock.When` together for a single member setup, **other than having the `When` condition moved into a setup callback or invoking regular `Setup` in an `if` block**?

The requirement is for Moq to keep any existing setup intact but still favor another setup under a certain condition.

I'm looking to do something like this:

```cs
mock.When(x => condition).Protected().Setup<int>("member").Returns(0);
```

Comment: This `When(x => condition)` is not familiar. When is defined as `ISetupConditionResult<T> When(Func<bool> condition)`  Version=4.13.1.0

Comment: Why not just use a normal condition and then do protected setup?

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for chiming in. :) I edited the question with additional details on the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to use both these features together.

`Mock<T>.When` is defined as

```
public ISetupConditionResult<T> When(Func<bool> condition)`
```

*Version=4.13.1.0*

And `ISetupConditionResult<T>` does not allow for the `Proteced<T>` extension method

```
public static IProtectedMock<T> Protected<T>(this Mock<T> mock) where T : class;
```

as it requires a `Mock<T>` as the target.

If possible, use a normal condition and then do the protected setup

```
if(condition) {
    mock.Protected().Setup<int>("member").Returns(0);
}
```

Comment: Q: *Why not just use a normal condition and then do the protected setup* A: Because doing it this way won't allow Moq to know that the setup is in fact conditional and that as such it shouldn't replace a potentially existing setup.

Comment: Also, I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean by "not familiar".

Comment: If you're okay with it, I would edit your answer to indicate that there's no way to use both the `When` and `Protected` features within `Moq` to achieve the desired result, and then accept it as the answer. Is that cool?

Comment: @Crono I have no problem with that, if it clarifies the answer for you.